How to recover from pyodbc cursor.fetchall() deadlock
Querying a SQL Server with pyodbc, sometimes cursor.execute() with a SELECT query completes successfully, but cursor.fetchall() gets deadlocked and throws an exception.
Code example:
self.cursor.execute(sql, *values)
self.rowcount = self.cursor.rowcount
results = self.cursor.fetchall()

Exception:

results = self.cursor.fetchall()
pyodbc.Error: ('40001', '[40001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 118) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205) (SQLFetch)')

What would be a proper way to recover there - re-run cursor.fetchall() or re-run cursor.execute() followed by cursor.fetchall()?

Neither, your connection is killed, so you need to re-create the connection as well as cursor.

@siggemannen, connection is killed is a wrong statement. My current code, if cursor.execute() was deadlocked and got exception with error code 1205 - LK_VICTIM, tries again after a delay for up to 5 times, using the same cursor, just running cursor.execute() again - that helps and usually requires not more than 2 attempts. I have just realized, that very rarely exception happens not at cursor.execute(), but at cursor.fetchall()

@testing-for-ya, that's for sure, yet deadlocks happen. Instead of crashing on them, I could log the problem and try several times again to succeed with the query. Even the exception text suggest the same: Rerun the transaction

@testing-for-ya in big multi purpose databases deadlocks can be fairly common, certainly it's not always possible to remove them all. So they count as a transient error, which you would normally retry using your transient error retry policy. Given only one process gets killed a second attempt should succeed.

@testing-for-ya no one said that ... You do both, retry, and log for investigation. On a database I manage I email out a deadlock report each day for a Dev to investigate. But I also retry them for good user experience.

To find out why fetchall is failing more than execute your should profile the SQL Server connection and see what is actually sent under the good. They must be working slightly differently and know that might help you optimise your queries.

Perhaps the cursor itself creates new connection when you do execute on it.
